# ReprojectImageTo3D corresponding pixel in image (Stereo Vision)

Tags: python, opencv, stereoscopy

I have a disparity map.

Based on the disparity map, hovering on the 'left image' displays:

`X` and `y` of the image, So if i hover on the top-left most, it will display `x:0, y:0`

The next step is to display distance of the specific pixel,to make my life easy, I will try to do it with `reprojectImageTo3D(disp, Q)`

I got `Q` from `stereoRectify`

now, `reprojectImageTo3D` in python, returns an `n by 3` matrix.

So I can see, it is a row of `x y z` coordinates. Wondering, how can I know which pixel are these coordinates correspond to?

This is a sample of the 3D points that I saved using numpy.savetxt

http://pastebin.com/wwDCYwjA

BTW: I'm doing everything in python, but GUI in Java, I don't have time to study GUI in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you correctly calculate your disparity map, you should get (n1,n2,1) dimensional array, where n1,n2 - number of image's pixels by axes, 1 - number of chanels (single channel, which contain distance in pixels between correspondent pixels from left and right images). You should check that by typing `disp.shape`. After that you should pass your disparity map's ndarray to `reprojectImageTo3D` function and get ndarray, which has (n1,n2,3) shape (third dimension contains X,Y,Z coords of 3D point). You can check that by typing:

```
threeDImage = reprojectImageTo3D(disp, Q)
print threeDImage.shape
```

And finally, since you made your disparity map based on left image, each pixel, which has coords x,y on left image (or disparity map), corresponds to threeDImage[x][y] 3D point. Keep in mind, that row:0, column:0 is the top-left element of the matrix, based on opencv handling images:

```
0/0---column--->
 |
 |
row
 |
 |
 v
```

Comment: hi, thanks, you're right, i realized i was doing something wrong. in python example, there was a mask to filter the disparity, and it reshaped the points into n by 3 matrix. i found out, originally, reprojectImageTo3D returns the same shape as the image :D