# OpenCV Pointcloud with cv2.reprojectImageTo3D getting deepth by n by 3 matrix

Tags: python, opencv, stereoscopy

I used the SBGM algorithm to create a disparity Image and it gets me a beautiful image

[image: Car disparity image]

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

 #load unrectified images
unimgR =cv2.imread("R.jpg")
unimgL =cv2.imread("L.jpg")

#load calibration from calibration file
calibration = np.load(r"C:\Users\XXX\PycharmProjects\rectify\Test3_OpenCV_Rectified.npz", allow_pickle=False)  # load variables from calibration file
imageSize = tuple(calibration["imageSize"])
leftMatrix = calibration["leftMatrix"]
leftDist = calibration["leftDist"]
leftMapX = calibration["leftMapX"]
leftMapY = calibration["leftMapY"]
leftROI = tuple(calibration["leftROI"])
rightMatrix = calibration["rightMatrix"]
rightDist = calibration["rightDist"]
rightMapX = calibration["rightMapX"]
rightMapY = calibration["rightMapY"]
rightROI = tuple(calibration["rightROI"])
disparityToDepthMap = calibration["disparityToDepthMap"]

# Rectify images (including monocular undistortion)
imgL = cv2.remap(unimgL, leftMapX, leftMapY, cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
imgR = cv2.remap(unimgR, rightMapX, rightMapY, cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

# SGBM Parameters 
window_size = 15  # wsize default 3; 5; 7 for SGBM reduced size image; 15 for SGBM full size image (1300px and above); 5 Works nicely
left_matcher = cv2.StereoSGBM_create(
    minDisparity=0,
    numDisparities=160,  # max_disp has to be dividable by 16 f. E. HH 192, 256
    blockSize=5,
    P1=8 * 3 * window_size ** 2,
    # wsize default 3; 5; 7 for SGBM reduced size image; 15 for SGBM full size image (1300px and above); 5 Works nicely
    P2=32 * 3 * window_size ** 2,
    disp12MaxDiff=1,
    uniquenessRatio=15,
    speckleWindowSize=0,
    speckleRange=2,
    preFilterCap=63,
    mode=cv2.STEREO_SGBM_MODE_SGBM_3WAY
)
right_matcher = cv2.ximgproc.createRightMatcher(left_matcher)

# FILTER Parameters
lmbda = 80000
sigma = 1.2
visual_multiplier = 1.0

# Weighted least squares filter to fill sparse (unpopulated) areas of the disparity map
    # by aligning the images edges and propagating disparity values from high- to low-confidence regions
wls_filter = cv2.ximgproc.createDisparityWLSFilter(matcher_left=left_matcher)
wls_filter.setLambda(lmbda)
wls_filter.setSigmaColor(sigma)

# Get depth information/disparity map using SGBM
displ = left_matcher.compute(imgL, imgR)  # .astype(np.float32)/16
dispr = right_matcher.compute(imgR, imgL)  # .astype(np.float32)/16
displ = np.int16(displ)
dispr = np.int16(dispr)

filteredImg = wls_filter.filter(displ, imgL, None, dispr)  # important to put "imgL" here!!!
filteredImg = cv2.normalize(src=filteredImg, dst=filteredImg, beta=0, alpha=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX);
filteredImg = np.uint8(filteredImg)

# Calculate 3D point cloud
pointCloud = cv2.reprojectImageTo3D(filteredImg,disparityToDepthMap) / 420  # needs to be divided by 420 to obtain metric values (80 without normalization)
print('...shape of the pointcloud:', pointCloud.shape)


print(pointCloud[1000][550])

cv2.imshow('Disparity Map', filteredImg)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Now i want to calculate the z-coordinate with pointCloud = cv2.reprojectImageTo3D acording to this [ReprojectImageTo3D corresponding pixel in image (Stereo Vision)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41923645/reprojectimageto3d-corresponding-pixel-in-image-stereo-Vision)

The point X,Y=1000,550 shout have the distance 10m, but it gives me [-0.09156016  0.09407288  0.32270285] (3dimension instead of 1)

I dont know what to do with this :(

I think ist a 3D Point of it, Right? But how can I get from an XY-Coordinate the distance Z-component in a single unit?

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you calculated the Euclidean distance from your X, Y coordinates to obtain the Z value, which is the distance you want.

```
print("Distance pointcloud in m :",np.sqrt(np.sum(np.power(pointCloud[1000][550],2))))
```